# Will Oracle database connection pool recover from the database server restart?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, connection-pooling

If the server running Oracle database reboots, this probably should invalidate all previous JDBC connections in the connection pool (running as part of application on another server).

Some connection pools can handle this, others require manual re-initialization, about Oracle I do not know. Would Oracle connection pool (versions 11g and up) be able to detect such situation and recover, or do I need to check for this myself and reinitialize?

Ideally, I would like to know also that would happen for the connection in use that has been borrowed from the pool. Would such connection proxy be able to use the rebooted server?

I have read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/connpoca.htm without particular success.

Comment: Have you tried anything to see if the Oracle Connection Pooling does automatic re-initialzation?

Comment: Surely I could setup the database, create the pool, reboot the server and check that happens, but with that amount of work asking question seems making sense.

Comment: Which "Oracle connection pool" do you mean? The one built into Oracle's JDBC driver? Or are you talking about shared server mode in Oracle itself? Or about something completely different?

Comment: Oracle JDBC driver built-in connection pool.

Comment: You can configure UCP to validate the connections: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12265/connect.htm#CHDIDJGH

Comment: I skimmed through the same doc as you did and found nothing, but this I do believe.  If this is a single instance server and not part of a RAC then all bets are off when the server goes by bye.  There IS no automagic reconnect and I pick right where I left off.  Connection pooling also has other perils, namely if you don't do it right, then next user to access the pool might end of see the other users data.